# What is a simplest way to add a flag to a number in JavaScript without compromising its functionality?

Tags: javascript

The code below:

```
var x = 600;
x.foo = true;
console.log("value: ",x);
console.log("foo: ",x.foo);
```

obviously this won't work, as JS numbers are unboxed. An obvious alternative would be to box all your numbers:

```
var x = { value: 600, foo: true }
console.log("value: ",x.value);
console.log("foo: ",x.foo);
```

but suppose you are using this method in a numerically expensive application. Then you get a heavy slowdown, as, now, you are creating a boxed object for every single number in your algorithm, which will wreak havoc in the memory management of the runtime. If all you need is a flag, though, a more lightweight option would be something like:

```
var x = flag_as_foo(600);
console.log("value: ",extract_value(x));
console.log("foo: ",is_foo(x));
```

where `flag_as_foo, flag_as_not_foo, is_foo and extract_value` could operate by flipping the bits on the number, or maybe using some clever arithmetic. My question is, what is the best way to implement it in JavaScript? This is not obvious, considering JS has no ints and a non-usual way to treat numbers.

**Please read the question. I am specifically asking for a bitwise or arithmetic solution of tagging a number.**

Comment: @downvoter: mind explaining?

Comment: In all my years of studying maths, my teachers never said that numbers have a concept of flags associated with them. What concept are you adding to mathematics that requires numbers to have flags (whatever that means)? (didn't downvote, but tempting)

Comment: I didn't downnvote, but; maybe you should give some clear examples of what you don't want. "...without using arrays/objects" is broadly disqualifying pretty fundamental language features. Any solution that relates two values (number amd flag) is going to have some kind of object *somewhere*. Is using `new Number` acceptable or not?

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but usually if you're storing multiple types of data that are meant to be associated, it's common practice to use an object that contains that data as separate properties.

If you decide to do something that has not been touched by anyone before, it might be a good idea to find out why.

Comment: No, it is not acceptable. I'm updating the answer, give me a minute.

Comment: I don't think it is possible since a number is not an Object.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 Numbers actually are Number objects: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number

Comment: @fernozzle - Technically everything in JavaScript is an extend of Object, but the documentation also says that Number is one of the primitive types.

Comment: @fernozzle `2` is different than `new Number(2)`

Comment: Okay, updated. Hope it is clearer now.

Comment: @Viclib Is there some feature in some language that allows what you want without using a (number) **object**, that I'm not aware of? Maybe I'm missing something obvious

Comment: Another *option*, is to keep a separate **single** object, that tracks the state of things. For example, if you want to flag `3` as `true`, you would have `var numberStates = {"3": true};`. And to get the boolean-forced value for a number (say, `3`), you would access `!!numberStates[3]`

Comment: Structs in C are **much** more lightweight and won't cause the memory havoc it causes in JavaScript. Not only that, you can simply use the last bit of a 32 int, for example, as the flag. If you simply replace every JS int by an object in a numerically intensive algorithm you'll be having a slowdown of 1 to 2 orders of magnitudes.

Comment: @Ian Well, I learned something today. But under what circumstances does `(2)` act differently than `Number(2)`?

Comment: @fernozzle Well, `new Number(2)`, not just `Number(2)`. But an immediate difference is getting the `typeof` them. `typeof 2` is "number", while `typeof new Number(2)` is "object". Based on that, logical comparisons would not work as well - even `new Number(2) === new Number(2)` is `false`. Normally, you don't use `new PrimitiveType()`

Comment: @fernozzle - `new Number(2)` is completely different from `2`. Actually, that's the situation for every primitive type. Try using `new Boolean(false)` in your codes and [have fun with that](http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/JsPYL/).

Comment: @Viclib You're asking for a bitwise solution -- are the numbers here always integers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript does, in fact, have *logical* integers, which are employed when using certain operations like bitwise booleans and shifts. Here's a set of functions that meet your criteria, assuming you only work with integer values:

```
function flag_as_foo(n) {
    n = n << 1;
    return n | 1;
}

function extract_value(n) {
    return n >> 1;
}

function is_foo(n) {
    return !!(n & 1);
}

var x = flag_as_foo(600);
console.log("value: ",extract_value(x));
console.log("foo: ",is_foo(x));
```

This reserves the least significant bit as a flag. The number is, of course, not usable as a proper value without running it through `extract_value` (as you've specified), since `x` here is not used as an integer, but as a string of bits (the first 31 of which represent a number, and the 32nd of which is a flag).

Note that the maximum number of usable numerical bits here becomes 31, as constrained by the logical ECMAScript operator [`ToInt32`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.5).

Comment: Uh interesting, you got the question. Can I still use numbers as floats?

Answer (score 1):

This is the closest you can get:

```
var a = new Number(1), b = new Number(2);
a.isBlue = true;        //you can do this since a and b are now an Object

console.log(a+b);       //3
console.log(a.isBlue);  //true
```

One major drawback is that you need extra effort to check if two numbers are the same:

```
a == b                  //false (assuming both have the same value)
```

Since they are now Objects, you would have to do this:

```
a.valueOf() === b.valueOf() //true
```

---

Update:

If you are a bitwise or arithmetic solution of tagging a number, what I would do is to utilize the sign of the number (assuming you only have possible numbers.) Otherwise, I can't think of any simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

> considering JS doesn't have integers

You can't store any sort of flag on an int to begin with. That said your best option would be to use an object literal. I do realize you stated in your question that you did not want to use objects. Yet doing something like

```
var a = {"number": "1337" , "color": "blue"}; 
alert(a.color);
```

seems to make the most sense.

Comment: This is unfeasible when you are using those numbers in a numerically expensive application. IE, that is unbearably slow.

Comment: I see. Now with your more detailed question I understand. Thanks